# Couldn't link source file to main file unless I include source file itself in the main file

Tags: c

Suppose I have 3 files, file.h file.c and fileMain.c. If I just include header file in the main file, it wouldn't link the source file. And gives error saying linker is not correct.
I am using vs-code as an IDE.
What might be an issue and how to fix it ?!

It only works if I add header file and source file both in the main file.

Comment: Add the `.c` files to the project. VS builder needs to know what files are used to build the executable.

Comment: What does "add" mean? `#include`? Something else? Generally, be specific with what you did. Show the code if it doubt, reduced to a [mcve]. Show the error message, don't just paraphrase like "gives error" or "linker is not correct". As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As long as the function name in file.c (definition) matches the name in file.h (declaration), you only need to add #include file.h in fileMain.c.

What it could be happening, is that file.c and file.h are in a different folder or a subfolder relative to fileMain.c (which I assume is the one holding your main function). As an experiment, try moving file.c and file.h to the same folder where fileMain.c is and see if it works.

If it does, it means that you need to tell vs-code where it must find the other files. How to do that will depend on what vs-code is using for compiling. For example, if it is using CMake + Make, you will have a file called CMakeLists.txt where those folders must be referenced.

Comment: Do you want to say, that VS Code automatically includes C files that accidentally happen to have same base name as a header file that is included, into the linker command without being told so via .json files?

Comment: Nope. You need to define somewhere the paths for where the compiler will look for source files. That will depend on what you are using to compile. CMake uses a CMakeLists.txt file. I guess you know some other compiler/linker that uses JSON files. The point is, your need to define that path, and usually, when you use the IDE to generate a new project, it already includes for you the path for your main file. Any other file inside that folder will be considered for compilation.

Comment: Then I don't know how the first sentence make any sense. Adding a header does solve the problem with missing implementation. The OP also did not mention CMake or other tool. Therefore it looks like they only use compile command in VS Code.